# Postfix refuses to send mail to some recipients

Tags: postfix, smtpd

I got a third-party application running on `localhost` trying to send mails with postfix via smtp on the same machine. The problem is that postfix seems to refuse mails to some recipients:

Content of `/var/log/mail`

```
Sep  1 00:05:35 myhost postfix/smtpd[20574]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Sep  1 00:05:35 myhost postfix/smtpd[20574]: B70E59A050: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Sep  1 00:05:35 myhost postfix/smtpd[20574]: lost connection after DATA (0 bytes) from localhost[127.0.0\
.1]
```

Meanwhile the sending application says:

```
cannot send mail to recipient@... please check connectivity
```

This error only happens with some recipients.

I checked my `main.cf`:

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.1/32, 192.76.247.2/32, 192.76.247.3/32, 192.76.247.4/32
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
```

Is there anything I missed? Or is there any other setting to restrict recipients?

Running postconf, `mail_version = 2.9.4` on SLES11 SP3

Sending mails to the same domains using

```
echo "test" | mail -s "test" notworking@domain.com
```

works without problems.

TCP dump output

```
11  0.001483    127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   SMTP    107 C: RCPT TO:myrec@domain.de>
12  0.002311    127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   SMTP    80  S: 250 2.1.5 Ok
13  0.002485    127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   SMTP    72  C: DATA
14  0.002555    127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   SMTP    103 S: 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
```

Comment: What domains are the non working emails going to? You sure they are formed correctly?

Comment: This doesn't look like it's postfix that rejects the message. Perhaps the sending application is not well-behaved and standards-compliant? Do you see a pattern on which recipients are failing?  At what rate does the sending application push it's messages? Maybe it is just the client (sending application) that times out? Check that you haven't run out of resources on the server, such as file descriptors, disk space, inodes, and so on.

Comment: @NickW : I edited the post accordingly, it does not seem to be about domains

Comment: @MattBianco : I'm not quite sure about the sending application (It is not opensource so I cannot see what it is doing exactly) but it surely works with this application and other mail recipients (at the same time). The resources on the server are fine.

Comment: Look at the SMTP conversation. Do a capture (e.g. "tcpdump -i lo -w /tmp/smtpfail.pcap port 25"), then load it into wireshark and reconstruct the TCP stream (right-mouse --> "follow TCP stream") and post the conversation as ASCII.

Comment: You could try using `strace` (or possibly `tcpdump`) to try to see what's going on. Other things to try are the `anvil` related postfix parameters to see if you can get the client to fail more frequently. I still think the sending application is the one to blame. How many emails in what time frame is it sending? (at what rate)

Comment: Thanks @NilsToedtmann, I pasted the TCP dump. Do I get it right, the data is empty?

Comment: Yeah, that's the sending program's issue..

Comment: This is your application's fault. Instead of sending the email message to postfix, it disconnects.

Comment: The tcpdump output might not show the complete SMTP handshake. To be sure, you should reconstruct the TCP stream e.g. with wireshark or tshark.

Another oddity: The brackets don't match in "RCPT TO:myrec@domain.de>". Or was that your edit?

From what i see so far, i second the others: looks like the client is screwing up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

< bot >Summarize the comments to answer section< /bot >

Maillog entry

```
lost connection after DATA (0 bytes)
```

means that your client disconnect itself after postfix announce `DATA` in SMTP transaction.

In normal transaction, client would send the header and body of emails after `DATA`. Your client behavior was abnormal because it disconnect without send a single byte to postfix. Your tcpdump was confirmed this behavior.

Comment: So the email client program is a problem. In our case we see this on Outlook, all of a sudden. What would be the solution?

Comment: I wanted to edit my comment but it's too late. It was a Windows 11 PC. Installed the latest Windows Update and then it just started working.